# Use of "confident that"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> The president of the French Republic organises a plebiscite when,
> **confident that** he has the backing of the popular majority on an
> important issue, the popular vote would help him to continue the
> general policy of his presidential mandate.
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

I want to know where does "confident that" belong to?

Does the sentence go "The president organises a plebicite when he is confident that"? In this case I don't know where the "the popular vote would help" part belongs to.

Or "Being confident that he has the support of the people the president organises a plebicite when popular vote would help him to continue general policy".
I am very confused about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence is about right.

The commas in the original act like brackets:
"The president of the French Republic organises a plebiscite when (confident that he has the backing of the popular majority on an important issue) the popular vote would help him to continue the general policy of his presidential mandate."

Read it without the phrase in brackets to get the main sense, then look at that phrase for additional detail.

The main point is that the president organises a plebiscite if it would help his general policy - but he would only do that if he was confident of winning.